# Unable to open in Development Build with the Unknown Scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, eas

Upon loading up a development build, I am given the **error** that I am **unable** to open my app via **development** build. My build builds correctly without errors.

However, when attempting to load up the app on my **phone** (in developer mode), I get this **error**. When I tap "**Development Build**" on my device, I get this error in my **terminal**:

> [redirect middleware]: Unable to determine redirect location for runtime 'custom' and platform 'ios'

[image]

I have tried to start the process of building and face this error every time. [See screenshot of error in terminal

[image]

Comment: You cannot install your dev app on an iOS device without a paid Apple Developer account. Without it, you're limited to the iOS simulator.

Comment: @MikeS. what about android?

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil, android has completely different rules which I know little about. After rereading the post, it appears the the OP is trying to launch the app in Expo browser, not a device. So I'm all confused. AFAIK, a strictly mobile app won't run in a Expo browser. So I don't know what the OP is trying to do.